# How to get rid of UniswapV2 K error?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I am writing a fairly simple smartcontract unising flash swap:

```
function uniswapV2Call(
    address _sender,
    uint _amount0,
    uint _amount1,
    bytes calldata _data
) external {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    uint amountToken = _amount0 == 0 ? _amount1 : _amount0;

    address sender = _sender;

    address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
    address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();


    require(
        msg.sender == UniswapV2Library.pairFor(dex1FactoryAddress, token0, token1),
        'Unauthorized'
    );

    require(_amount0 == 0 || _amount1 == 0);

    path[0] = _amount0 == 0 ? token1 : token0;
    path[1] = _amount0 == 0 ? token0 : token1;

    IERC20 token = IERC20(_amount0 == 0 ? token1 : token0);
    IERC20 otherToken = IERC20(_amount0 == 0 ? token0 : token1);

    token.approve(address(sushiRouter), amountToken);

    uint amountRequired = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(
        dex1FactoryAddress,
        amountToken,
        path
    )[0];

    uint amountReceived = sushiRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountToken,
        amountRequired,
        path,
        sender,
        deadline
    )[1];

    assert(otherToken.transfer(msg.sender, amountRequired));
    assert(otherToken.transfer(tx.origin, amountReceived - amountRequired));
}
```

I always have UniswapV2 K. I have read the doc, but I have no clue what is the issue.

Any Help?

Comment: Hi there. Is either `token0` or `token1` a rebasing token? Or do either of them take a fee on every transfer?

Comment: Hi no they dont take a fee. Also I don't think they are a rebasing token. I created them from openzeppelin and i tried with Wmatic and Weth.

Comment: @Stefdelec do you have any transaction hash which shows failed transaction? there are a lot of parameters involved which can affect the outcome of the code you are trying to execute.

Comment: https://explorer-mainnet.maticvigil.com/tx/0xaaf480b81d15d77ffa325892fa7041287c13298d65314a7ab80137975fe37588/internal-transactions

Comment: https://explorer-mainnet.maticvigil.com/tx/0xfb6eede68bb2f7b5df403322bc46c942f7b5160b52178278c545476fac04ec80/logs

Comment: but I guess it is coming from my code as I have 'uniswapV2 k' error on a lot of different tokens

Comment: I’m curious to know if you found a solution.. I have been trying to do a flashswaps for days. Each time I have an error.. impossible to find a qorking example even on testnet.. very frustrating..